# Variation in alignment?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a visual effect where a piece of text is adjusted left, right, center, whatever, but the origin of the alignment varies from line to line by a few pixels. This would work well with small paragraphs, and would provide a break from monotony.

Except I have no idea how to implement this...

Comment: Can you use jQuery? Can you force where the line breaks should be? (Then it's easy. Making this dynamically is hard - interested to see what comes up)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an [excellent CSS demo](http://meyerweb.com/eric/css/edge/slantastic/demo.html) that I came across a long time back that uses a bunch of floated DIVs coupled with the "diagonal border" trick to create a neat effect -- I believe you're looking for something similar.

If you only need the alignment, just plain DIVs will do -- float and clear them left/right and give them varying widths, and they will cause the text to flow around them. For example:

```
.spacer {
  float: left;
  clear: left;
  height: 1em;
  /* vary the width using inline styles */
}
```

The diagonal borders add to the effect by separating the text from the background using different colours.